# Poner IMG al lado del texto

Tags: javascript, html, css

Me estoy apoyando usando bootstrap y estaba intentando hacer que *banderamx* se sitúe al lado de la palabra "español" ya que es para un menú de idiomas pero sin tocar el css ya que al intentarlo me modifica todo y es un caos, y por eso intenté hacerlo desde html directo solo para esa parte.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```html
<li class="dropdown" data-animation="fadeIn">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="corporate.html"
    data-title="Home"> IDIOMA </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu no-border-radius">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/banderamx.png"  width="20" style="display: flex;" alt="Espa;ol"></a>Español</li>
     <li><a href="coreanohome.html"> Coreano </a></li>
     <li><a href="#"> Ingles </a></li>
     <li><a href="chinohome.html"> Chino </a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="img/banderamx.png"  width="20" alt="Espa;ol"></a>Español</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ayúdate con esto

```css
.flag{
  display: inline-block;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.flag2{
  display: run-in;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<li class="dropdown" data-animation="fadeIn">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="corporate.html"
data-title="Home"> IDIOMA </a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu no-border-radius">
<li>
  <a href="#" class="flag">
    <img src="https://images.emojiterra.com/twitter/v13.1/512px/1f1f2-1f1fd.png"  width="15" alt="Espa;ol">
    </a> Español
</li>
<li>
  <div class="flag2">
  <a href="#" class="flag">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Flag_of_Mexico.svg/980px-Flag_of_Mexico.svg.png"  width="20" alt="Espa;ol">
     Español</a>
    </div>
</li>
 <li><a href="coreanohome.html"> Coreano </a></li>
 <li><a href="#"> Ingles </a></li>
 <li><a href="chinohome.html"> Chino </a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="img/banderamx.png"  width="20" alt="Espa;ol"></a>Español</li>
</ul>`introducir el código aquí`
</li>
```

Yo preferiría la segunda pues, hasta la palabra **Español** es "clickeable" pero eso ya depende de tu diseño.

PD: La primer bandera tiene un padding (la imagen).

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!! probare las dos manera para practicar y entender las diferencias de cada opcion

Comment: Marca la respuesta como aceptada para que no se pierda ✌